# SAPUI5 - file uploader with undefined parametrs

Tags: file-upload, sapui5

I'm trying to implement a sap.ui.unified.FileUploader but, when using the change function, the parameters from the event (e) are undefined. The strangest thing is that I have an example on the JS fidler and it works there, but not on my page.
Here's the code:

```
var f = new sap.ui.unified.FileUploader({ 
     uploadUrl : "",
     buttonText : "Upload",  
     fileType : "csv",  
     maximumFileSize : 1,
     icon : "sap-icon://upload",
     change : function(e){
         console.log("aqui");
         var file = e.getParameter("files") && e.getParameter("files")[0];
         console.log(file);
         if (file && window.FileReader){  
             var reader = new FileReader();  
             var that = this;  
             reader.onload = function(evn) {  
                 var strCSV= evn.target.result; //string in CSV 
                 alert(strCSV);
             };
             reader.readAsText(file);  
         }
     }
 });
```

The file var, turns to be undefined on my page.
Any thoughts?
Thanks!

UPDATE: when I try to get the getParameters method from the event e, I only get the id and the name, and in the fidler i'm getting the id , name and the files... Heres the fidler link http://jsbin.com/vonotekaso/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

In the view file:

```
new sap.ui.unified.FileUploader({
   uploadUrl : "serviceURL",
   name: "simpleUploader",   
   uploadOnChange: false,  
   sendXHR: true,  
   useMultipart: false,
})
```

in combination with a button like:

```
new sap.m.Button({
   text : "{i18n>UPLOAD}",
   icon : "sap-icon://upload",
   type : sap.m.ButtonType.Accept,
   press : [ oController.onStartUpload, oController ]
})
```

In corresponding controller file:

```
onStartUpload : function(oEvent) {
    var oFileUploader = // TODO get the file uploader
    var sFile = oFileUploader.getValue();
    if (sFile==="") {
        // TODO no file selected
        return;
    }
    oFileUploader.destroyHeaderParameters();
    that.getModel("modelName").refreshSecurityToken();  
    oFileUploader.insertHeaderParameter(new sap.ui.unified.FileUploaderParameter({name: "x-csrf-token", value: that.getModel("modelName").getHeaders()['x-csrf-token'] }));
    oFileUploader.insertHeaderParameter(new sap.ui.unified.FileUploaderParameter({name: "slug", value: oFileUploader.getValue() }));
    oFileUploader.upload();     
},
```